# Keras model's validation loss doesn't match the loss function output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am working on a biomedical image segmentation project. I am using U-net model for the job. The problem is, when i train the model, the validation loss doesn't seem to be practical.

I used the **dice_coef_loss** as loss function, as well as, in the *metric*. The result of the training is the below graph. The graph clearly shows that validation loss is not following my loss function, cause the two graphs are distinguishable. Though, the train loss does follow the train dice_coef_loss values.

*(The first image from the left is training and validation loss, third one is tarining and validation **dice_coef_loss** as metric)*

[The history graph of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7pDC.png)

*(Sorry i am not yet eligible to embed an image, please check the link)*

## Here is my model

```
def unet(input_size=(256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    return Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])
```

## Here is the loss function

```
import keras.backend as K
smooth=100

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_truef=K.flatten(y_true)
    y_predf=K.flatten(y_pred)
    And=K.sum(y_truef* y_predf)
    return((2* And + smooth) / (K.sum(y_truef) + K.sum(y_predf) + smooth))

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

## Compilation

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=["binary_accuracy", dice_coef_loss, iou])
```

## Note

I have tried:

- learning rate tuning
- tuning batch size
- data augmentation
- changing the loss function

If any one want to look at the code here is the [link to kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/mdbadiuzzamanshuvo/brats-using-u-net-kfolded?scriptVersionId=36567381)

## Addition Note

To make my self clear :

**The 1st and second graph was generated from a same function using same dataset (either from train or validation time), so I want the train_loss curve from 1st plot equal to train_dice_coef_loss from 3rd plot. And val_loss curve from 1st plot equal to val_dice_coef_loss from 3rd plot.**

But unfortunately val_loss curve doesn't match val_dice_coef_loss curve.

P.S. I am new here. Any suggestion to improve my question is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking, the plots you show are training and validation loss/metrics, but these do not have to match, as they are evaluated on different datasets, so I am not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: i have used a single function as loss function and as a metric. Their values has to be the same on both time. Training time values of both graph should match, as well as the test time values. **I am not asking for train and test graph to be same, I am asking the test graph from both plot (1st and 3rd) have to match, as they are evaluated on the same dataset**

Comment: From your code, it seems you're using augmentation in the generators and there are many random operations. Are you sure it's just not a seed issue?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Firstly, as far I know, Image Data Generator is doing just random transformation of images and mask on the same seed here, no augmentation. Secondly, This random transformation was used only for train data not on validation data. In the validation generator, an empty dictionary was passed to the generator so that it doesn't do any random transformation on validation data. Thirdly, it doesn't seem to be a seed issue to me. Finally, thank you for your help.

Comment: In the training, if the loss and metrics are evaluated at different points of time (before backprop and after backprop), they may not agree, but here it shouldn't be an issue. I also don't see any regularization in the model which can penalize the loss function or anything. The only flaw can be with your data pipeline. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example with dummy data where the loss and the metrics don't agree (ignoring numerical rounding) similar to this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11mvsCX5uzajQet5G6g4ReI5Hvy2b5zzQ?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi there is a kernel in colab training on another dataset with similar problem : [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AMf4V_zNIEItFf-XERiaGWfnpigwhExJ?usp=sharing)

Comment: `keras` logs is broken and there are too many issues that may not be fixed. Replace all your `keras` imports with `tensorflow.keras`, your val metrics and val loss shouldn't be drastically different.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi That solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, **ZabirAlNazi** suggested it was a problem of the used library. Changing the imports from keras to tensorflow.keras solved that issue.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model, save_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Activation, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda, Dense, Conv2D
```